# Composer move from prefer-source to prefer-dist

Tags: php, composer-php

Is there any way with Composer to update from using prefer-source, to using prefer-dist?  I'd like to deploy the dist files, but develop with source files.  Running `composer update --prefer-dist` doesn't seem to work though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like first deleting the vendor folder, then updating will do the job.

Comment: The issue with this is I need to install them into custom directories, as I'm working with a legacy system; and so just deleting the vendor directory wouldn't be enough.  The other directories can't just be deleted due to them also having custom code in them.  Not the best system I know, but it's the only one that'll work with the legacy system were stuck with.

Comment: So the directories with mixed filed do also contain the repository directory from Git (or even SVN)? How does that fit together? However, delete whatever was installed by Composer in whatever directory, not deleting anything not installed by Composer, and then run the update again.

Comment: There are various packages in the plugins directory, some are installed via composer, some are custom packages.  All files in that directory are ignored, then some are expressly added to git (by adding to the path to the ignore file prepended with an !).  The issue is that the packages from composer need to be installed via source for development, and from dist for production; and the CI server doesn't know which ones are from composer and which ones are custom.  So I was hoping composer could make that distinction itself, doesn't sound like it can though.

Comment: I don't think your use case is a common one, and that is the reason Composer does not offer very much help right now. My best advice would be to try to relocate anything that is Composer-managed into the vendor directory. Next best thing would be to get rid of the source installation once for everything (with a huge manual effort), and start developing these parts separately from now on. If you can't develop it in isolation, it probably is no good candidate being a Composer library.